# if the get_lengths(k) more than 20 then do something else do something

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, python-3.x

```
k=['qwertyuiop','asdfghjklqwertyuiopzxcvbnm','qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmzxcvbnm']
def get_lengths(k):
    return [len(i) for i in k]

if m > 20 for m in get_lengths(k):
    print("1")
else:
    print("-1")
```

how do I get the results? or output of "1" when the string is more than 20 characters, and get "-1" when the string is less than or equal to 20 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there,

```
print("\n".join("1" if m > 20 else "-1" for m in get_lengths(k)))
```

Or,

```
for m in get_lengths(k):
    if m > 20:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(-1)
```